# Error :'Type 'keyof ChartTypeRegistry' is not assignable to type '"bar"'. Type '"line"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'.'

Tags: typescript, chart.js, react-typescript

I'm trying to integrate Chart.js with React Typescript. I'm a beginner to chart.js and when I'm going with the project I am getting the following error.

Compiled with problems:X

> ERROR in src/components/BarCharts.tsx:63:24
>
> TS2322: Type 'ChartData<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, (number |
> ScatterDataPoint | BubbleDataPoint | null)[], unknown>' is not
> assignable to type 'ChartData<"bar", (number | ScatterDataPoint |
> BubbleDataPoint | null)[], unknown>'.   Type 'keyof ChartTypeRegistry'
> is not assignable to type '"bar"'.
> Type '"line"' is not assignable to type '"bar"'.
> 61 |   return (
> 62 |
>
> > 63 |       
> > |                        ^^^^
> > 64 |     
> > 65 |   );
> > 66 | };

So here is the BarCharts.tsx Component.

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { ChartData } from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Country } from '../types';

interface Props {
  countries: Country[];
}

const options = {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
};

const ChartWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
`;

const BarChart: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ countries }) => {
  const generateChartData = (): ChartData => {
    const data: number[] = [];
    const labels: string[] = [];

    countries.forEach((country) => {
      data.push(country.NewConfirmed);
      labels.push(country.Country);
    });

    return {
      labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'New Confirmed',
          data,
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          ],
          borderWidth: 1,
        },
      ],
    };
  };

  return (
    <ChartWrapper>
      <Bar type="bar" data={generateChartData()} options={options} />
    </ChartWrapper>
  );
};

export default BarChart;
```

Could someone please help me in this case? What is the error I have done in here ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass "bar" as a type argument to the ChartData type, like this `ChartData<"bar">`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved (perhaps with codeblocks or documentation links)